# Server Side Includes not working on IIS 7 - Classic ASP

Tags: iis-7, configuration, asp-classic, server-side-includes

OK So I have Windows 7 with IIS 7
Server Side includes and all the other stuff required in "Turn Windows Features on or off"
ISAPI.DLL module in IIS is enabled.
Allow parent paths is enables on all locations.

When I run a file with an include, what I see is "< ? %"  the ? is in a black diamond. And I can see the actual code instead of the included page being processed and served by IIS.

The Parent Page throws an ASP Exception which means ASP itself is working.

The include file is a connection string so nothing out of the ordinary and its extension is also .asp.

I have read about 50+ suggestions on various sites including ALL on stackoverflow but no joy.

BTW, the include runs perfectly if i call it directly from browser.

Comment: Look at your include file.  It looks like you have some extra character between a "<" and a "%" which means that one of you asp script blocks isn't recognised as such

Comment: Another thought - have saved both the include and the main file with the same encoding.  Open them in notepad, File -> Save As and look at what's selected in the encoding dropdown

Comment: Hi John, I copied the whole thing to my server at the office and it worked straight. The extra space you see was added by me here because the textbox here wont accept that tag combined. The extra character is something that shows up after the page is run.

Comment: Can you post your code? Maybe you just have small typo.

Comment: This is why I suggested you check the encoding of your files.  If you save a file with UTF-8 encoding then open it in an old editor which doesn't support UTF-8 (eg Homesite 4.5) you see loads of strange characters appearing

Answer (score -1):

Please set enable parent path = true in IIS for this website, this will allow access parent page

Comment: Sorry I have given up on this. I have tried everything but still nothing works. I have been working on IIS for more than 10 years. Due to time constraints, I am abandoning this whole thing and working off a Windows 2003 server. Thanks all for your assistance.